# Copy Ms Access data to a dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I actually need to create an automation project. For that i need to compare the data of two files and display the differences in their results.
One file should be an Ms Excel file and the other should be an Access file.
I am able to take Ms Excel file data into a data dictionary. But i am unable to do so for Ms Access file.
For this,I want to read the data from an MS Access file to a Data table or Data Dictionary. I am unable to do it with OLEDB.
What steps should i follow?
Any further help on how to automate this project will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't give specific information on the problem you're experiencing, but as a first step are you following steps given here for .NET to MS Access databases: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Thanks for modifying your question. I've just followed instructions at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171893.aspx and successfully created a connection to Northwind 2007.accdb on my local drive. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and a Console App (not a Windows Forms app as stated in the link). This is the connection string I ended up with:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="HelperApp.Properties.Settings.Northwind_2007ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Northwind 2007.accdb&quot;"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

I don't know if this is a one-off task or one that will have to be done frequently, but if you could import the data into SQL Server you could use Visual Studio's very cool database compare feature: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/773455/Schema-Data-Comparison-of-Two-Databases-with-Visua

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It seemed really helpful and something that can get the work done. But unfortunately i am getting an error which says, "Cannot start your application. The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user." I am stuck at this point and nothing seems to help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this error message is coming while trying to add a connection to the Northwind 2007.accdb.